# Using AVERAGEIFS to Populate a Table in Excel

Tags: excel, average

**UPDATE2:  I'm including another screenshot.  I'm guessing this is probably why I'm getting errors.**

[image]

**UPDATE.  Phrased another way, you could say it like this: "calculate the average of columns J and K (from the 1st screenshot) for all the instances where the following conditions are met: column K is less than or equal to 1638, column M is "1" (the flare is on), it's January 1st 2016, and you are the the first 3-hour block for the day (0:00 - 2:59).  Then do the same thing for all of the other 3-hour blocks in the day.  Then do it all over again for the 2nd day of January and so on.  Why do I keep getting "#VALUE!#** ?

This one is going to be complicated so I will try to break this down as best I can.  What I'm asking isn't 100% necessary, but it would drastically speed up this process.  Below are two screenshots to help illustrate what is going on.

[image]

[image]

In the first screenshot, the rows extend on for about 200,000 rows or so.  column A is month, B is the date, C is the time, and D is a column that I created that tells you which 3-hour block you are in for the current day.  For example, there are 8, 3-hour blocks in the day (0:00-2:59, 3:00 - 5:59, etc.).  So where it says "1" in the screenshot, it changes to reflect the correct 3-hour block as you scroll through the sheet.

In the second screenshot, you will see I have setup a table for the month of January.  Here is what I've been trying to do with the `AVERAGEIFS` formula:

If you look at cell B4, for example, what should go there is the following:

**calculate the average of columns J and K (from the 1st screenshot) for all places where column K has a value of 1638 or lower, column M is equal to "1", column D (time slot) is equal to "1", and the day is the first  **

If I can figure out how to make this work properly, I would like to then simply apply the formula to the others cells in the table as appropriate.  So, C5 on the second screenshot should also be the average, but instead it should be for column D is equal to "2", the day is equal to "1", column K has a value of 1638 or lower, and column M is still equal to "1".  Does this make sense?

Here is what I thought it might be for cell B4 in the second screenshot:

`=AVERAGEIFS(E6:K262024, L6:L262024, "<=1638", M6:M262024, "=1", A6:A262024, "=January", B6:262024, DAY(B6:B262024)=1, D6:262024, "=1")`

Yeah.  That's really intense.  All I got from that was "#VALUE!", which doesn't help at all.  Any suggestion to this would be amazing and probably a learning opportunity for everyone since this is a very complicated example of using this function.

Comment: Put the day in a helper column like you have the month and use that in your averageifs().  You can't use Day() in the averageifs like that.

Comment: Yep, I just did that as well, and I keep getting the stupid "#VALUE!" error.   The only thing I can think is that maybe it's because there are some entries (not generated by me) in columns J and K that are not numbers.  There are some places there where it says "-OVER".  I'm assuming this might be what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"average_range" input should be a single column. I would suggest trying to narrow this range to a single column for each MIN and MAX, then averaging the two.

Also, I'm seeing in your original formula your criteria range for column D (time slot?) is missing the D. `D6:262024`

Comment: make this a statement not a question and you have an answer, and probably the correct one.  I just noticed that myself.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a single column because I was able to make it work earlier on a much smaller scale.  When I was doing it earlier though, I was only telling the ranges to look in places where the values were GOING to be what the criteria said.  Now I'm expanding to include the entire sheet where things like "day" and "time slot" change and it messes up.  I think because in columns J and K there are places there where it says "-OVER" instead of a number.  That could be what's throwing it off.

Comment: @Ryan_C no Averageifs() will automatically skip any text and not consider them at all.  Also I just tried a simple AverageIFS() and with the multi column, it failed.

Comment: Interesting.  Well then.  This just keeps getting more complicated.  I can do this all manually, but I was trying to brainstorm to see if there was a way to do it quicker.

Comment: More precisely ["Unlike the range and criteria arguments in the AVERAGEIF function, in AVERAGEIFS each criteria_range must be the same size and shape as sum_range"](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIFS-function-48910c45-1fc0-4389-a028-f7c5c3001690)

Comment: @ScottCraner you are correct.  I guess it has to be one range.

Comment: @Andrew L you are also correct.  Thanks for that info...apparently it does indeed have to be one column.

Comment: @Ryan_C I don't think it's too complicated (when thinking of doing this manually). Just =average(averageifs(K, ...),averageifs(L, ...)) ...

Comment: You can also add a column for temporary averaging each row and then use it as the range for the formula.

Comment: Now I'm getting a "#DIV/0!" error.  Ugh.  Progress I guess!

Comment: @Ryan_C Probably just a typo. It means there are no values that fit the given conditions. Good luck.

Comment: @AndrewL I added a new screenshot.  Have a look...do you think that could be the cause?

Comment: Maybe because you have a "#DIV/0!" values within the data?

Comment: @EBH that's what I'm thinking.  This data was automatically generated by a data logger, so I'm still figuring out what to change those "#DIV/0!" values to.

Comment: @Ryan_C Keep them blank, and they will be treated as missing values. Add `IF(ISERROR(AVERAGE(...)),"",AVERAGE(...))`, or something like that...

Comment: @EBH so wait,  with the formula you just wrote, if it IS an error, then what are you suggesting the argument be?

Comment: @Ryan_C just an empty string `""`, so `AVERAGEIFS` will ignore it.

Comment: ohhhh ok I see what you're saying